# Execute VBA using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Ok, this may be a long shot but in MS Access, is it possible to execute VBA using SQL? I'm looking to write a query that runs either a single VBA statement or a Sub. Basically, what I'm trying to do is modify the hidden attribute of a table using SQL.

MS makes enough weird decisions with Office implementations that I'm mildly hopeful this is one of those cases.

Comment: I know you can do the opposite really really easily. Application.SetHiddenAttribute acTable, "TableName", True

Comment: Where are you planning on executing this SQL Statement? Is this an Access query you're looking to write?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a VBA function and use the function's return value as a field expression in a query.  However, you must run the query from within an Access application session. Otherwise the db engine will not be able to use your custom function.

```
SELECT YourFunction() AS result;
```

Comment: I believe if you execute this using DAO it will work just fine, not just in Access. Won't work from JET/ACE though.

Comment: What do you mean "not just in Access"?  The only way it can work is from within an Access application instance.

Comment: I've never found a way to do it except from within an Access session.  The db engine needs the Access expression service to make use of a UDF.  The expression service is only available within an Access application instance.  If you have working code which does it without an Access session, please show us.

Comment: While this doesn't solve my greater problem outside of the scope of this question, it does answer my direct question, with a solution even. I was trying to determine if there was a way for me to manipulate a .accdb server-side on a Linux server without a running Access instance before delivering it to the end user. Seems like a headache if not impossibility without doing a lot of work.

Comment: One other thing I'll add is that you can only call Functions from the SQL, and not Sub Procedures. However, the way around that is to call the Sub from within the Function.

Comment: You should forget this concept of 'server side' when using access. It is not a server based database it id a file base database - all work is performed on the client. So yuo certainly cannot do this on linux as there is no MS Access client that runs on Linux. You could implement somekind of remote-execution solution to execute your MS Access functions on a computer that does have MS Access installed though.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years (thankfully) since I used Access, but to the best of my knowledge, that's simply not possible. You can use VBA to execute SQL, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user-defined functions within an SQL query ( http://www.sqlexamples.info/SQL/inlineudf.htm ). I doubt Excel checks what you do inside this function, so you probably can do whatever you like.